# Diferença de service, repositories e controller

Tags: jpa

> Qual a diferença de services, repositories e controller em JPA.

Sei que o repositories trabalha com a abstração de dados. Quem pega os dados do banco?

As classes mapeadas (@Entity), e o controller e o service?

Comment: JPA não possui estes artefatos (services, repositories e controllers). Especifique um contexto onde eles existam para dar escopo à resposta.

Comment: Como mencionado na resposta anterior, o JPA não possui essa arquitetura por padrão. Porém, se você a implementou, o padrão fica da seguinte forma: O Controller fica responsável pela lógica de serviços, consumindo os métodos do Service. O Service fica responsável por realizar a chamada das operações com o banco, enquanto os Repositories abrigam as suas inserções/consultas/atualizações/remoções.

Comment: @Caffé

Implementei com spring mvc spring data e spring security.

Comment: @Nikofoxxx

Como assim o service fica responsável pelas chamadas do banco, já que você disse que o repository faz o crude?

Comment: Aqui no meu projeto, o service fica responsável por chamar os métodos do Repository e montar os objetos necessários para retornar ao Controller. O Repository é onde fica, por exemplo, as consultas SQL. Entende?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como já dito, JPA é somente a tecnologia de acesso ao banco de dados. Com ele você pode usar os Design Patterns (padrão de design) que não fazem parte do JPA especificamente.

**Repository** é um Design Pattern onde os dados são obtidos do banco de dados e ocorre também a regra de negócio. Este retorna objetos de domínio que seriam as Entidades (classes anotadas com @Entity).

**DAO** é outro Design Pattern onde somente há a comunicação com o banco de dados sem regra de negócio.

**Service** seria outro Desing Pattern onde há somente a regra de negócio e não tem acesso direto ao banco de dados.

**Controller** Ele é utilizado para lidar com a ligação da View com as outras partes do sistema que são a regra de negócio e banco de dados.

---

Ao desenvolver um sistema você vai escolher quais você vai utilizar. Pode ser Entity + DAO + Service, Entity + Repository, usar um Objeto sendo Entity e Repository ao mesmo tempo.
Ambos os casos ligados com a view através do Controller.